# Flutter marker appears but not map

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-platform

I am using flutter and trying to implement a google map.

As you can see from the picture, the marker renders in the right position, it just has no actual map rendered. Additionally, I am trying to have the address search bar autocomplete, and nothing is resulting as well. You can check out the code for this in the second block below.

```
Expanded(
  child: GoogleMap(
    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated, initialCameraPosition:
      CameraPosition(
        target: _center,
        zoom: 11.0,
      ),
     markers: {
       Marker(markerId: MarkerId(searchField.text),
              position: _center)
     },
    ),
  )
```

I already created an API key, and put it into my app. I followed the tutorials for incorporating it in, but am still left with nothing.

For iOS, I registered it in my AppDelegate.swift and in the geomethods for the address searching mechanism. I also prompted for location permissions in the Info.plist. Is there anything I am missing?

```
// geoMethods
final geoMethods = GeoMethods(
    googleApiKey: '(My API key was here, deleted for obvious reasons)',
    language: 'en',
    countryCode: 'us',
    countryCodes: ['us', 'es', 'co'],
    country: 'United States',
    city: 'New York',
  );

...
...
...

// Passed in for the search bar text field
onTap: () => showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => AddressSearchBuilder.deft(
    geoMethods: geoMethods,
    controller: field,
    builder: AddressDialogBuilder(
      color: Color(0xFFE64225),
    ),
    onDone: (Address address) {
      print(address);
    },
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once check your **API key**. some time map not load because of expired API key. if **googleApiKey** is working fine then check your
`AppDelegate.swift` file

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps


@UIApplicationMain
 @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("your_ googleApiKey_here")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```